movie in which guerrillas give a hand grenade to a baby
I am trying to remember the name of a movie (set perhaps in Asia) in which a guerilla group terrorizes an innocent outpost (possible a field hospital run by white people) by giving a hand grenade to a baby, and shooting anybody who moves to intervene. This movie would have come out in the last fifteen years I think.

Was it Beyond Borders from 2003?

